Guacamole: May I have connections, shared with multiple users, featuring their own credentials?
So my colleagues and I share a pretty good hundred RDP/SSH connections.
The connections may change slightly over time, like a new IP, name, or port.
The systems require individual users to connect to.
The credentials may change over time, like password changes, domain migration, whatever.
There are about 3 different credentials used across all services, per user.
The credentials are not part of our internal domain, but from the customer.
I would like to...

create these 150 connections once, or better import them as (json,yaml,csv)
create and maintain 3 credentials per user
share the connections between users, so I have one single source of truth for the latest connection details
connect user credentials to the connections, e.g. by alias.

Basically that's what we do with Devolutions Remote Desktop Manager today, using credentials which then are link to KeePass.
When we share the latest structure, nobody's password is shared, because the credentials referenced by the connections are just  references (UUID) on their own (to a KeePass entry).
Since the credentials are setup once, and then referenced, we just have to update these 3 credentials per update/sync.
Why then switching to guac? - because its FOSS, web based and therefore does not require local installations.
Without being connected to the companies network, the service/connections are irrelevant, since they are only available from there.

#pushpushpush!!
